# Removing KeyEvents from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, keylistener, keyevent

### Question:

I have a class implementing a `KeyListener` to collect a list of pressed keys. The list is then delegated to an instance of `KeyListener` to be handled. Each time a key is released, it must be removed from the list.

My issue is that they are not being removed from the list because the `KeyEvent` I store in the list when pressed is not the same as the `KeyEvent` generated when the Key is released. This results in *none of the KeyEvents being removed* and thus, they accumulate.

What changes must I make to ensure that I can remove a `KeyEvent` with only knowledge of a different `KeyEvent` for the same key (the remove method checks with `.equals()`)?

---

### Code:

```
KeyListener subject;
    ArrayList<KeyEvent> pressed = new ArrayList<KeyEvent>();

    public MultiKeyListener(KeyListener subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        pressed.add(k);
        if (subject != null && pressed.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pressed.size(); i++) {
                subject.keyPressed(pressed.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
        pressed.remove(k);
        if (subject != null && pressed.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pressed.size(); i++) {
                subject.keyPressed(pressed.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {

    }
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more why you are passing the events to yet another key listener, and why you send all key press events both when the keys are pressed and when they are released?

Comment: @KevinSheehan The purpose is so that I can decouple the handling of the KeyEvents so that I don't need to write a new `MultiKeyListener` every time that I write a new class. Instead, I write a KeyListener and pass it to a MultiKeyListener.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused why you can't keep track of all the keys that are being pressed and then just check against that wherever it is needed? You won't have different listeners receiving different key inputs?

Comment: @KevinSheehan Currently, I'm using KeyListeners to move a player and each player gives its own KeyListener. It seems counter intuitive to write the MultiKeyListener every time I need new behaviours/classes (player control, menus, etc). It's easiest to write a simple KeyListener for each, and add them to the window's MultiKeyListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wrapper around KeyEvent.

```
public class KeyEventWrapper
 {
     private KeyEvent keyEvent;

     public KeyEventWrapper(KeyEvent keyEvent)
      {
         this.keyEvent = keyEvent;
      }  

     public KeyEvent getKeyEvent()
      {
         return keyEvent;
      }

     public boolean equals(Object object)
      {
          if(object instanceof KeyEventWrapper)
            {
                KeyEventWrapper wrapper = (KeyEventWrapper) (object);
                KeyEvent k = wrapper.getKeyEvent();

                return (this.keyEvent.getKeyCode() == k.getKeyCode());
            } 
          return false;
      }

     public int hashCode()
       {
           return this.keyEvent.getKeyCode();
       }
 }
```

Now, you can use an ArrayList of this wrapper object instead of KeyEvent.

```
ArrayList<KeyEventWrapper> pressed = new ArrayList<KeyEventWrapper>();
... 
pressed.add(new (KeyEventWrapper(k));
...
pressed.remove(new (KeyEventWrapper(k));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to be storing which Key is pressed, not the KeyEvent itself. A new event occurs every time a key is pressed, typed, or released. What you want to keep track of is either the [KeyCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29) or [KeyChar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29).

Edit: Just another suggestion, you might want to consider using a `Set` instead of a `List` to keep track of which keys have been pressed. A single key realistically cannot be pressed more than once.

Comment: I'm delegating to another KeyListener; I must pass a KeyEvent to it. Should I remove `KeyListener subject` in order to allow this functionality?

Comment: I originally didn't upvote because I didn't quite see how your answer was applicable. Your suggestion about using a Set was insightful, but did not meet my needs. Although your answer was not useful to me, it is very sound advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should iterate **pressed** List from the end to the start and remove the first occurrence of KeyEvent there that has the same KeyCode. Something like this:

```
@Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
        for (int i=pressed.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
             if (pressed.get(i).getKeyCode()==k.getKeyCode()) {
                 pressed.remove(i);
                 break;
             }
        }
    ......
```